# 'tmElements_t' does not name a type

Tags: arduino-uno, time

I've connected a real time clock ZS-042 to my Arduino Uno. I tried to set the time, using an example from DS1307RTC library. Here is my code:

```
#include <DS1307RTC.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <Wire.h>

*const* char *monthName[12] = {
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};

  tmElements_t tm;//it says that problem is in here

void setup() {

  bool parse=false;
  bool config=false;

  // get the date and time the compiler was run
  if (getDate(__DATE__) && getTime(__TIME__)) {
    parse = true;
    // and configure the RTC with this info
    if (RTC.write(tm)) {
      config = true;
    }
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; // wait for Arduino Serial Monitor
  delay(200);
  if (parse && config) {
    Serial.print("DS1307 configured Time=");
    Serial.print(__TIME__);
    Serial.print(", Date=");
    Serial.println(__DATE__);
  } else if (parse) {
    Serial.println("DS1307 Communication Error :-{");
    Serial.println("Please check your circuitry");
  } else {
    Serial.print("Could not parse info from the compiler, Time=\"");
    Serial.print(__TIME__);
    Serial.print("\", Date=\"");
    Serial.print(__DATE__);
    Serial.println("\"");
  }
}

void loop() {
}

bool getTime(const char *str)
{
  int Hour, Min, Sec;

  if (sscanf(str, "%d:%d:%d", &Hour, &Min, &Sec) != 3) return false;
  tm.Hour = Hour;
  tm.Minute = Min;
  tm.Second = Sec;
  return true;
}

bool getDate(const char *str)
{
  char Month[12];
  int Day, Year;
  uint8_t monthIndex;

  if (sscanf(str, "%s %d %d", Month, &Day, &Year) != 3) return false;
  for (monthIndex = 0; monthIndex < 12; monthIndex++) {
    if (strcmp(Month, monthName[monthIndex]) == 0) break;
  }
  if (monthIndex >= 12) return false;
  tm.Day = Day;
  tm.Month = monthIndex + 1;
  tm.Year = CalendarYrToTm(Year);
  return true;
}
```

and this is my output:

```
Arduino: 1.6.12 (Windows 10), Плата:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"

In file included from C:\Users\6939~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_566010\SetTime.ino:1:0:

C:\Users\папа\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS1307RTC/DS1307RTC.h:19:22: error: 'tmElements_t' has not been declared

     static bool read(tmElements_t &tm);

                      ^

C:\Users\папа\Documents\Arduino\libraries\DS1307RTC/DS1307RTC.h:20:23: error: 'tmElements_t' has not been declared

     static bool write(tmElements_t &tm);

                       ^

SetTime:10: error: 'tmElements_t' does not name a type

   tmElements_t tm;

   ^

C:\Users\6939~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_566010\SetTime.ino: In function 'void setup()':

SetTime:21: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

     if (RTC.write(tm)) {

                     ^

C:\Users\6939~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_566010\SetTime.ino: In function 'bool getTime(const char*)':

SetTime:54: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tm.Hour = Hour;

     ^

SetTime:55: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tm.Minute = Min;

     ^

SetTime:56: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tm.Second = Sec;

     ^

C:\Users\6939~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_566010\SetTime.ino: In function 'bool getDate(const char*)':

SetTime:71: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tm.Day = Day;

     ^

SetTime:72: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tm.Month = monthIndex + 1;

     ^

SetTime:73: error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

   tm.Year = CalendarYrToTm(Year);

     ^

exit status 1
'tmElements_t' does not name a type
```

Comment: Check the order of header files and check the dependencies. Do you have the right libraries. Looks like you have modified this example sketch; https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/DS1307RTC/blob/master/examples/SetTime/SetTime.ino

Comment: [IDE 1.6.10: compilation of sketches wich time library fails](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=415314.0)

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange.  You can take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the best out of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the compiler does not know what tmElements_t means.

It is defined in TimeLib.h

In your program you reference Time.h instead, where it is not defined.

So:  Change

```
include <Time.h>
```

to

```
include <TimeLib.h>
```

and it should clear that error.

Comment: `Time.h` was changed to `TimeLib.h` specifically to combat this problem. The compiler started providing `time.h`, and on operating systems like Windows that use a case-insensitive filesystem it confuses `Time.h` and `time.h`.

Comment: Thank you for help! It works! The problem was in TimeLib.h. Literally, it wasn't in my lib, so i had to re-install it. Then I changed include as you said and it works.

Comment: But for now I've got another trouble. My serial port doesn't print anything.

Comment: Take out the `while (!Serial)` - once you do the `Serial.begin(9600)` you can assume it is ready to receive output.  Also, be aware that in the Arduino IDE, opening the serial monitor will restart your program.